# show JS alert and redirect to function

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a function that loads a page and add a new user.

I want to show an alert(); and redirect/load a different function to change the url.

I have used

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;page.php"></meta>
<script>
  alert("Pergunta eliminada com sucesso juntamente com as respostas!");
</script
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Question" as a title is not specific at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the window.location.href property to set the URL you want to redirect to:

`window.location.href = "http://path.to.url/"`;

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                location.replace("profile/profile.php");
              </script>';
```

you can use the above one to replace a file using js in php  and can even add an alert here